# I have problems to trying to add a get the median functionality in my MIPS program

Tags: assembly, mips

I write the following MIPS program that take 10 integers from user, then output (min value, max value, and average), then I added instructions to get the median (starting from line 72, from the comment # Calculate median), every time I run the program after entering the 10 numbers I get the following exception (Runtime exception at 0x004000e0: fetch address not aligned on word boundary 0x10010005).

```
.data 

array: .space 40 #10 X 4(byte)
prompt: .asciiz "Please enter 10 random numbers :\n"
sort: .asciiz "\nThe descending order of the numbers are :\n"
sum: .asciiz "\n\nThe Sum of all numbers are : "
average: .asciiz "\n\nThe average of all the number is : "
max: .asciiz "\n\nThe maximum number is : "
min: .asciiz "\n\nThe minimum number is : "
space: .asciiz " "
dot: .asciiz "."
median: .asciiz "\n\nThe median of the numbers is: "

.text

.globl main

main:
li $v0, 4
la $a0, prompt #print out prompt
syscall

la $s0, array #load array into register s0

LoopInput:
li $v0, 5 #input numbers
syscall
sw $v0, 0($s0) # $v0 = i
addi $s0, $s0,4 #move array position
addi $t0, $t0,1 #loop array where i++
bne $t0, 10,LoopInput #for(t1=0;t1!=10;t1++) g

la $s0, array
sub $t0, $t0,$t0

Sorting: #sorting number from big to small
beq $t1,9, ConSort #if t1=9, go to conSort
lw $s1, 0($s0) #load the number in the first location into $s1
lw $s2, 4($s0) #load the number in the second location into $s2
addi $s0, $s0, 4 #update array position
addi $t1, $t1, 1 #move array position #for(s1=0;s1!=9;s1++)
bge $s1, $s2, Sorting #if s1>s2, back to sorting
sw $s1, 0($s0) #exchange position
sw $s2, -4($s0)
bne $t1, 9, Sorting #if t1!=9, go back to sorting

ConSort:
la $s0, array #continue sort with the same way
addi $t0, $t0, 1 #keep sorting the other numbers
addi $t1, $t0, 0
bne $t0, 9, Sorting #if t0!=9, go back to sorting

li $v0, 4 #print out prompt
la $a0, sort
syscall
la $s0, array
sub $t0, $t0, $t0

PrintSort:
li $v0, 1 #print sorting
lw $a0, 0($s0)
syscall
li $v0, 4
la $a0, space #print out prompt
syscall
addi $s0, $s0, 4
addi $t0, $t0, 1
bne $t0, 10, PrintSort #if t0!=10, go to printsort

# Calculate median
li $t4, 5 # t4 = 5
la $s0, array # s0 points to the beginning of the array
add $s0, $s0, $t4 # s0 points to the middle element of the array
lw $t5, 0($s0) # t5 = array[5]
li $v0, 4 # print message
la $a0, median # message to print: "The median of the numbers is: "
syscall
move $a0, $t5 # print median value
li $v0, 1 # print integer
syscall


sub $t0, $t0, $t0
sub $t1, $t1, $t1
sub $t2, $t2, $t2
sub $t3, $t3, $t3
la $s0, array #load array number to $s0
li $v0, 4 #print out prompt
la $a0, sum
syscall

SumA:
lw $t2, 0($s0) #load first $t2 to $s0
addi $s0, $s0,4 #update the array[s0] position
add $t3, $t2, $t3 #t3=t2+t3
addi $t0, $t0, 1 #t0= i++
bne $t0, 10, SumA #if t0!=10, go back to SumAll

move $a0, $t3 #move $t3 to $a0
li $v0, 1 #print out the sum of all numbers
syscall

li $v0, 4

la $a0, average #print out prompt
syscall

addi $t6, $t6, 10 #t6=10
div $t3, $t6 #t3=t3/10
mflo $s5 #move quotient to s5
mfhi $s3 #move remainder to s3

move $a0, $s5 #move s5 to a0
li $v0, 1 #print out quotient
syscall

li $v0, 4
la $a0, dot #print out dot
syscall

move $a0, $s3 #move s3to a0
li $v0, 1 #print out remainder
syscall
la $s0, array #load array into s0
li $v0, 4 #print out prompt
la $a0, max
syscall

lw $t5, 0($s0) #load number in array into t5
move $a0, $t5 #move t5 to a0
li $v0, 1 #print out number
syscall

li $v0, 4 #print out prompt
la $a0, min
syscall

lw $t4 , 36($s0) #load number in array into t4
move $a0, $t4 #move t4 to a0
li $v0, 1 #print out number
syscall

li $v0, 10
syscall #end of program
```

From my understating the problem caused by an attempt to access memory at an address that is not aligned on a word boundary.

Comment: Use your debugger/simulator to see which instruction is causing the error then work backwards to see why. From a quick glance it is because you do `add $s0, $s0, $t4` with `$t4=5`. You forgot to scale by item size.

Comment: @Jester , i have changed the operand of the instruction li $t4, 5 to 4 it work but still give me a wrong median value, the instruction that cause the error is (lw $t5, 0($s0))

Comment: Offset 4 would be the second element in the array, which is not what you want.

Comment: Element at index 5 is at byte offset of 20.  Why? Because byte offset needs to be byte count and thus we need to incorporate the element size (this is called scaling, to convert from simple index to byte offset): `5 x sizeof(int) = 5 x 4 = 20`.

Answer (score 1):

Unlike C, assembly doesn't auto-scale your pointer arithmetic/array indexing. It seems you understand this, since you always use `addi $s0,$s0,4` to advance to the next entry in your array, as an `int` on the 32-bit MIPS hardware takes up 4 bytes. The only place you made an error was here:

```
li $t4, 5 # t4 = 5
la $s0, array # s0 points to the beginning of the array
add $s0, $s0, $t4 # s0 points to the middle element of the array
```

Presumably, you want the middle value which is actually going to require you to use `li $t4, 20`. I'll use a chart below to explain this. I'll assume that your array is located at memory address `0x00000000` (it isn't, but it's just to make the demonstration a bit easier.) If, for example, the user inputs the numbers 2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10, and 11, this is what your array would look like in memory after being sorted (assuming a little-endian CPU)

```
0x00000000: 02 00 00 00
0x00000004: 03 00 00 00
0x00000008: 04 00 00 00
0x0000000C: 05 00 00 00
0x00000010: 06 00 00 00
0x00000014: 07 00 00 00 (this is what you will get when you load from offset 20)
0x00000018: 08 00 00 00
0x0000001C: 09 00 00 00
0x00000020: 0A 00 00 00 (ten)
0x00000024: 0B 00 00 00 (eleven)
```

Now since there are an odd number of values, you're going to have to average the two in the center. So you'll load from `0($s0)` and `-4($s0)`, add them, and bit shift right once.

Comment: There's no need to use an `add` instruction at all if the offset is also a constant.  `la $s0, array + 4*5`

Comment: That's true, and it's the easier solution. I just wanted to demonstrate that this works even if you're not adding a constant.